# Open and Closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble understanding the idea of an open set, I know the definition of it is :

***Let $G$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$. Then for each $x \in G $, there is a real number $r>0$ such that every point $y \in \mathbb{R}^p$ satisfying $\|x-y\| < r$ also belongs to the set $G$***.

For example: Let $G = \{x\in \mathbb{R} : 0< x <1\}$. This is open in $\mathbb{R}$ , but if I let $x = .5$ and $r=3$, I have a $y = 2 \in \mathbb{R}$ that $|.5-2| = 1.5 < 3$ but $2 \notin G$.

Comment: Look at the part of the definition that says "there is". It is not a problem if you find a ball that falls outside as long as there is some other that doesn't. For example, same center, radius $r= 0.4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stressing on the comment by @uldek.

A point $p$ is an interior point of a set $E$ if **there is** a neighbourhood $N$ of $p$ such that $N\subset E$.

Your argument is trying to modify the definition to **every** neighbourhood $N$ of $p \subset E$, but your choice of a radius includes points from the $E^{c}$.

Answer (score 1):

For open set we have to check each point is interior point and to check interior point we have to show **existence** of a particular radius such that a ball of that radius around that point is fully inside the set.

You have chosen radius to be $3$ that might not work.

Comment: but why wouldn't 3 work? If every x in G is less than 1 then the distance between any two x in G would be less than 1 and 1 is less than 3 ?